# Failed to start behavior on Pepper robot with Choregraphe

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I'm actually new at choregraphe and I don't know what happened to my robot pepper whenever I start to run my behavior. It keeps showing this
"One of the possible reasons is that the current behavior is not in your package content." Also even I just place a simple behavior like "say" hello. Can you guys explain what should I do with this? Because I'm a bit annoyed on packaging and installing it on the robot.

I tried to use other computer and installed it with choregraphe but its seems the robot itself is the problem. I tried to run it on a virtual robot but it works fine.

the error message is this "the current behavior could not be found"

also whenever I tried to run it multiple times it crashes the application.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you attempt to run does not seem to be in the project's manifest.
To correct that, have a look at the [project properties](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/panels/project_content_panel.html).
The picture below is borrowed from the documentation.
[image]

The panel "A" is the view of the package content.
You must make sure that the behavior you want to run is checked.

Note that when you create a new project, it already contains one behavior that is part of the package content.